# Pygame Jumping Performance Inconsistency

Tags: python, pygame

When I jump in the game that I am making, the jump height is different depending on computer and map even thought I am using frame rate capping. For example, when I ran the game on my computer I could jump two tiles high but when I ran it on another computer I could only jump about one tile high.

The way I cap the framerate is by using the deltaTime of the current amount of milliseconds since pygame.init() was called and the milliseconds from the last loop iteration since pygame.init() was called.

Here is how I set the deltaTime (this is at the beginning of the game loop):

```
prevTime = curTime;
    curTime = pygame.time.get_ticks();
    if ((curTime - prevTime) / 1000.0) <= 0.0:
        deltaTime = -((curTime - prevTime) / 1000.0);
    else:
        deltaTime = ((curTime - prevTime) / 1000.0);
```

And here is the player class:

```
import pygame;
import Globals;
import Object;
import Tile;
import MAP_HANDLER;

class Obj_Player(Object.Obj_Base):
    #0 - FRAME_RIGHT_IDLE
    #1 - FRAME_RIGHT_WALK_1
    #2 - FRAME_RIGHT_WALK_2
    #3 - FRAME_RIGHT_IDLE
    #4 - FRAME_RIGHT_WALK_1
    #5 - FRAME_RIGHT_WALK_2
    Frame = 0;
    frameTime = 0.0;
    isRightFoot = True;
    #0 - LEFT
    #1 - RIGHT
    lastMoveKeyPress = 0;
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
        self.speed = 300;
        self.Surface = pygame.image.load("Sprites/PLAYER_SPRITES.png");
        self.OBJ_TYPE = 1;
        self.Gravity = 10.0;
        self.collisionTop = (0, 0, 0, 0);
        self.collisionBottom = (0, 0, 0, 0);
        self.collisionRight = (0, 0, 0, 0);
        self.collisionLeft = (0, 0, 0, 0);

    def Update(self, deltaTime, cameraX):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed();

        self.cameraX = cameraX;

        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.lastMoveKeyPress = 1;
            self.velX = self.speed;
            self.frameTime += deltaTime;

            if self.frameTime >= 0.25:
                if self.isRightFoot == True:
                    if self.Frame == 1:
                        self.Frame = 0;
                        self.isRightFoot = False;
                    else:
                        self.Frame = 1;
                elif self.isRightFoot == False:
                    if self.Frame == 2:
                        self.Frame = 0;
                        self.isRightFoot = True;
                    else:
                        self.Frame = 2;
                self.frameTime = 0.0;
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.lastMoveKeyPress = 0;
            self.velX = -self.speed;
            self.frameTime += deltaTime;

            if self.frameTime >= 0.25:
                if self.isRightFoot == True:
                    if self.Frame == 4:
                        self.Frame = 3;
                        self.isRightFoot = False;
                    else:
                        self.Frame = 4;
                elif self.isRightFoot == False:
                    if self.Frame == 5:
                        self.Frame = 3;
                        self.isRightFoot = True;
                    else:
                        self.Frame = 5;
                self.frameTime = 0.0;
        else:
            if self.lastMoveKeyPress == 0:
                self.Frame = 3;
            else:
                self.Frame = 0;
            self.velX = 0.0;
            self.frameTime = 0.25;

        if self.x <= 0.0:
            self.x = 0.0;

        if self.x >= Globals.WINDOW_WIDTH - self.w:
            self.x = Globals.WINDOW_WIDTH - self.w;

        if self.y <= 0.0:
            self.y = 0.0;

        for i in range(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArraySize()):
            if self.collisionTop[0] < int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getX() - cameraX) + MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getW() and self.collisionTop[0] + self.collisionTop[2] > int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getX() - cameraX) and self.collisionTop[1] < int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getY()) + MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getH() and self.collisionTop[1] + self.collisionTop[3] > int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getY()):
                if MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getTileType() != '0':
                    self.y = MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getY() + 64;
                    self.velY = 0.0;

            if self.collisionRight[0] < int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getX() - cameraX) + MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getW() and self.collisionRight[0] + self.collisionRight[2] > int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getX() - cameraX) and self.collisionRight[1] < int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getY()) + MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getH() and self.collisionRight[1] + self.collisionRight[3] > int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getY()):
                if MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getTileType() != '0':
                    self.velX = 0.0;
                    self.cameraX -= 1;

            if self.collisionLeft[0] < int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getX() - cameraX) + MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getW() and self.collisionLeft[0] + self.collisionLeft[2] > int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getX() - cameraX) and self.collisionLeft[1] < int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getY()) + MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getH() and self.collisionLeft[1] + self.collisionLeft[3] > int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getY()):
                if MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getTileType() != '0':
                    self.velX = 0.0;
                    self.cameraX += 1;

            if self.collisionBottom[0] < int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getX() - cameraX) + MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getW() and self.collisionBottom[0] + self.collisionBottom[2] > int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getX() - cameraX) and self.collisionBottom[1] < int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getY()) + MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getH() and self.collisionBottom[1] + self.collisionBottom[3] > int(MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getY()):
                if MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getTileType() != '0':
                    self.velY = 0.0;
                    self.y = MAP_HANDLER.getTileArray(i).getY() - self.h;
                    self.falling = False;
                    self.jumping = False;
                    if key[pygame.K_UP] and self.jumping != True:
                        self.jumping = True;
                        self.velY = -400.0;
            else:
                self.falling = True;

        if self.falling == True or self.jumping == True:
            if self.velY < 500.0:
                self.velY += self.Gravity;

        #self.x += self.velX * deltaTime;
        self.cameraX += self.velX * deltaTime;
        self.y += self.velY * deltaTime;

        if self.Frame == 0:
            self.imgX = 0;
            self.imgY = 0;
            self.imgW = 16;
            self.imgH = 32;
        elif self.Frame == 1:
            self.imgX = 16;
            self.imgY = 0;
            self.imgW = 16;
            self.imgH = 32;
        elif self.Frame == 2:
            self.imgX = 31;
            self.imgY = 0;
            self.imgW = 16;
            self.imgH = 32;
        elif self.Frame == 3:
            self.imgX = 79;
            self.imgY = 0;
            self.imgW = 16;
            self.imgH = 32;
        elif self.Frame == 4:
            self.imgX = 49;
            self.imgY = 0;
            self.imgW = 16;
            self.imgH = 32;
        elif self.Frame == 5:
            self.imgX = 64;
            self.imgY = 0;
            self.imgW = 16;
            self.imgH = 32;
        else:
            self.Frame = 0;

        self.w = 64;
        self.h = 128;

        self.collisionTop = (self.x  + 15, self.y, self.w - 30, 5);
        self.collisionBottom = (self.x + 15, self.y + self.h - 5, self.w - 30, 5);
        self.collisionLeft = (self.x, self.y + 5, 5, self.h - 10);
        self.collisionRight = (self.x + self.w - 5, self.y + 5, 5, self.h - 10);

    def Draw(self, window):
        if self.x >= 0 - self.w and self.x <= Globals.WINDOW_WIDTH and self.y >= 0 - self.h and self.y <= Globals.WINDOW_HEIGHT:
            crop = pygame.Surface((self.imgW, self.imgH));
            crop.blit(self.Surface, (0, 0), (self.imgX, self.imgY, self.imgW, self.imgH));
            crop = pygame.transform.scale(crop, (self.w, self.h));
            crop.set_colorkey((48, 4, 0));
            window.blit(crop, (self.x, int(self.y)));
```

Comment: How do you go about capping? What method do you use to cap the system?

Comment: The deltaTime is what I use (as explained in my question). I multiply the velocity and the deltaTime to move the player in the x and y direction (for example, x += xVelocity * deltaTime). This is to prevent everything from moving too fast.

Comment: You need to create [mcve] . It's very difficult debugging the code when we have to read through hundreds of lines of code, especially when it doesn't follow python convention, such as variable and method/function names should be named with `lower_case` and classes `CamelCase`, and you shouldn't have comma after every line.

Comment: So you calculate the time, but what do you do with it?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Python accepts semicolons as line delimiters. And simply because the OP doesn't follow  the current PEP naming convention is no reason to not help.

Comment: For simplicity, create a clock `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` and call the method `delta_time = clock.ticks(fps)`. The method will return the time (in milliseconds, so divide the result by 1000 to get it in seconds) between each call and delay the program if it's being called faster then the `fps`

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I don't mean that we shouldn't help, I mean that it's difficult to debug that much code written in unconventional style. It will be easier to get help by reducing the problem and use common Python conventions.

Comment: My bad, it should be [`delta_time = clock.tick(fps)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick), and not `ticks()`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! :)